# How to insert data from .sql into Django table?

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to insert some initial data into a django table.
I've tried sqlcustom and sqlall, but it doesn't seems to work...
And followed the instructions and created a .sql file with some inserts statements in it, like this:

INSERT INTO `charts_wave` (id, ...) VALUES (...);

This file it is in the following path:

project/charts/sql/wave.sql

Maybe I didn't understand the purpose of sqlcustom and sqlall.
After running the commands, I run one final the syncdb command.
Next I test it by calling the Wave.objects.all() in the python shell and it returns a empty list.

What I'm doing wrong?? How can I insert this data with the sql file. 
The method with fixtures it seems hardcode for the really extensive data that I've to insert.
Thanks for now.

Comment: why not use fixtures instead of sql?

Comment: I have to do a lot of inserts, like 2000, so it doesn´t seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you are looking for [Django fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/). They provide a way to import initial data into your Django apps. So instead of importing your data yourself, including a fixture in your app, when you will run syncdb, the data will be automatically imported.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, english is not my first language x). Are you saying that I have to use fixtures or not? I have 2000 lines of inserts, with fixtures it is a lot of work. With the instructions in that link, in the part of Providing initial SQL data they say to use sqlcustom and sqlall, but it seems not to work. And I say this because, like I said, when I run the Wave.objects.all() the console returns an empty list. Thanks for the attention.